# Faster efficient way to crop netcdf in R

Tags: r, netcdf, r-raster, terra

I have a .nc/netcdf file which is about 1GB in size. Trying to crop and make it smaller with the following code:

```
  r <- terra::rast("myfile.nc")
  r2 <- terra::crop(x = r, y=terra::ext(-79, -72, 0, 12.4))
```

fails in a 16GB RAM machine. By *failing* I mean it does not return any results in 15 minutes and freezes my RStudio session if I try to stop the running code. Thus I have no error message to post here.

What alternative to `terra::crop()` should I consider to use on netcdf files?

Comment: Do you want to try another package? https://docs.ropensci.org/tidync/reference/hyper_filter.html

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @crestor. I am trying to avoid further dependencies on this project (and new-ish packages). I will first give Rob Hij's suggestion a try before trying  tidync.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with (NetCDF) files with many layers (time steps) can be very slow when using (a standard approach with) GDAL, which is what terra uses. I hope to fix this over the coming months. What you want to do may go much faster with `raster` because it approaches the data as a three-dimensional array (it is not looping over layers). So I would suggest

```
library(raster)
r <- brick("myfile.nc")
r2 <- crop(r, extent(-79, -72, 0, 12.4))
```

Comment: Thanks Rob. It wasn't clear to me that terra:: is not yet equivalent to raster:: for these operations

Comment: This (many time steps ncdf) may be the one thing where terra is not yet better than or equal to raster.